# antd Global Theme Color Setting

Tags: python, reactjs, django, antd

I am new to antd and need to set the global theme to one of the antd colour palettes.
I am building an app using Django, React and antd.

I have installed the colours package:

```
npm install @ant-design/colors --save
```

Then I added the palette to my Layout.js file, my default layout:

```
import { purple } from '@ant-design/colors';
```

Which shows up in the console

```
console.log(purple);
console.log(purple.primary);
```

I am struggling with how to make this override the default colours and display the purple ones.

I have tried to include in the theme:

```
const theme = { primary: purple[5] };
```

I have also tried to add to the token:

```
const {
    token: { purple, colorBgContainer, borderRadiusLG },
} = theme.useToken();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the global theme to one of the antd color palettes, you can use the ConfigProvider component provided by antd. Here's how you can achieve that:

```
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
import { purple } from '@ant-design/colors';

// Wrap your entire application with ConfigProvider
ReactDOM.render(
  <ConfigProvider theme={{ primary: purple[5] }}>
    <App />
  </ConfigProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

By wrapping your entire application with ConfigProvider, you can set the theme prop to define the primary color. In this case, purple[5] is set as the primary color.

This approach will override the default colors used by antd components with the selected palette. Now, all antd components within your application will use the purple color palette as their primary color.

Comment: Is there a benefit of using the reactDOM.render, over using the token= method I have used?

Comment: Using ReactDOM.render with ConfigProvider allows you to set the theme globally for your entire application at the root level. This means that all antd components within your application will automatically use the specified theme without the need to pass it down as props to each individual component.

On the other hand, using the token method within components allows you to access theme tokens defined within antd's design system. These tokens are predefined values for various aspects of the UI such as colors, spacing, typography, etc.

Comment: While you can use these tokens to customize specific components or styles within your application, it won't globally set the theme for all antd components.

Comment: The choice between these approaches depends on your specific requirements. If you want to globally set a theme for all antd components in your application, using ReactDOM.render with ConfigProvider is the recommended approach. If you only need to customize specific components or styles, using the token method within components may be more appropriate

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I parse multiple conditions their?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out from the antd website:

https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#customize-design-token

By wrapping the layout in a ConfigProvider:

```
<ConfigProvider
        theme={{
        token: {
            // Seed Token
            colorPrimary: purple.primary,
        },
        }}
    >
<Layout>
  ...
</Layout>
</ConfigProvider>
```

This sets the Global colour theme.
If there is a better way please let me know.